# Trouble with Saving SharedPreferences and reading them

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am working on a log in screen and main menu screen. Right now I had it working until I tried to implement a method if the user is logged in or not. The main issue according to logcat is a nullpointerexception and I cannot for the life of me figure how to fix this issue. If someone could give me input that would be great. Any help at this point would be wonderful.

Here is My Main Menu activity:

```
package com.chonbonstudios.LOLTOOLs;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TitleMenu extends Activity {

TextView SummonerId;
TextView SummonerName;
TextView SummonerLevel;


long SummonerIdA = 0;
String SummonerNameA = "";
long SummonerLevelA = 0;
int profileIconIdA = 0;

SharedPreferences data;
SharedPreferences data1;
SharedPreferences data2;
SharedPreferences data3;
SharedPreferences data4;

boolean loggedIn = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    data4 = getSharedPreferences("LoggedInStatus", 0);
    loggedIn = data4.getBoolean("LoggedInStatus", false);


    if (loggedIn == true){

    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(TitleMenu.this, LoginActivity.class));
        this.finish();
    }


    SummonerIdA = getIntent().getLongExtra("SummonerIdTag", 0);
    SummonerNameA = getIntent().getStringExtra("SummonerNameTag");
    SummonerLevelA = getIntent().getLongExtra("SummonerLevelTag", 0);
    profileIconIdA = getIntent().getIntExtra("SummonerProfileIconIdTag", 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putLong("SummonerIdTag", SummonerIdA);
    editor.commit();
    finish();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = data1.edit();
    editor1.putString("SummonerNameTag", SummonerNameA);
    editor1.commit();
    finish();


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = data2.edit();
    editor2.putLong("SummonerLevelTag", SummonerLevelA);
    editor2.commit();
    finish();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = data3.edit();
    editor3.putInt("SummonerProfileIconIdTag", profileIconIdA);
    editor3.commit();
    finish();

    data = getSharedPreferences("SummonerIdTag", 0);
    SummonerIdA = data.getLong("SummonerIdTag", 0);

    data1 = getSharedPreferences("SummonerNameTag", 0);
    SummonerNameA = data1.getString("SummonerNameTag", "");

    data2 = getSharedPreferences("SummonerLevelTag", 0);
    SummonerLevelA = data2.getLong("SummonerLevelTag", 0);

    data3 = getSharedPreferences("SummonerProfileIconIdTag", 0);
    profileIconIdA = data3.getInt("SummonerProfileIconIdTag", 0);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_menu);

    SummonerId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSummonerId);
    SummonerLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSummonerLevel);
    SummonerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSummonerName);


    SummonerId.setText(String.valueOf("My Id: " + SummonerIdA));
    SummonerLevel.setText(String.valueOf(SummonerLevelA));
    SummonerName.setText(String.valueOf(SummonerNameA));






    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.title_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_LofOff:
        startActivity(new Intent(TitleMenu.this, LoginActivity.class));
        this.finish();

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}


    }
```

and my Log In activity:

```
package com.chonbonstudios.LOLTOOLs;



import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
public String array_spinner[];

Button Login;
EditText Name;
String loginName = "";
String url ="";
TextView one;
TextView two;
Spinner Area;
String AreaCode;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUMMONERID = "id";
private static final String TAG_SUMMONERNAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_SUMMONERLEVEL = "summonerLevel";
private static final String TAG_PROFILEICON = "profileIconId";


long SummonerIdA = 0;
String SummonerNameA = "";
long SummonerLevelA = 0;
int profileIconIdA = 0;

SharedPreferences data4;

public boolean loggedIn = false;


private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Typeface typeFace =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fq.ttf");

    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSummonerNameLogin);
    one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    Area = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinArea);

    Login.setTypeface(typeFace);
    one.setTypeface(typeFace);
    two.setTypeface(typeFace);
    Name.setTypeface(typeFace);

    array_spinner= new String[7];
    array_spinner[0]="NA";
    array_spinner[1]="BR";
    array_spinner[2]="EUW";
    array_spinner[3]="EUNE";
    array_spinner[4]="LAN";
    array_spinner[5]="LAS";
    array_spinner[6]="OCE";


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
    Area.setAdapter(adapter);
    Area.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View V) {

            if(Name.getText().length() != 0){
                loginName = Name.getText().toString();

                url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + AreaCode  + "/v1.3/summoner/by-name/" + loginName + "?api_key=NOAPIKEYFORYOU";




                new GetUserData().execute();




            } else{
                toastNoNameMethod();

            }       

        }

    });



}



private void toastNoNameMethod() {
    Toast toastNoName = Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter a Summoner Name",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toastNoName.show();

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

    int i = Area.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch(i){
    case 0: AreaCode = "na"; break;
    case 1: AreaCode = "br" ; break;
    case 2: AreaCode = "euw"; break;
    case 3: AreaCode = "eune"; break;
    case 4: AreaCode = "lan"; break;
    case 5: AreaCode = "las"; break;
    case 6: AreaCode = "oce"; break;

    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private class GetUserData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String userDataSummoner = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + userDataSummoner);

        if (userDataSummoner != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(userDataSummoner);
                JSONObject userData = jsonObj.getJSONObject(loginName);

                SummonerIdA = userData.getLong(TAG_SUMMONERID);
                SummonerNameA = userData.getString(TAG_SUMMONERNAME);
                SummonerLevelA = userData.getLong(TAG_SUMMONERLEVEL);
                profileIconIdA = userData.getInt(TAG_PROFILEICON);



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");

        }


        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TitleMenu.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("SummonerNameTag", SummonerNameA);
        myIntent.putExtra("SummonerIdTag", SummonerIdA);
        myIntent.putExtra("SummonerLevelTag", SummonerLevelA);
        myIntent.putExtra("SummonerProfileIconIdTag", profileIconIdA);
        startActivity(myIntent);


        loggedIn = true;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = data4.edit();
        editor4.putBoolean("LoggedInStatus", loggedIn);
        editor4.commit();
        finish();




    }


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

My Log cat:

```
03-21 00:12:16.350: D/AndroidRuntime(31329): Shutting down VM
03-21 00:12:16.350: W/dalvikvm(31329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41df9700)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chonbonstudios.LOLTOOLs/com.chonbonstudios.LOLTOOLs.TitleMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at com.chonbonstudios.LOLTOOLs.TitleMenu.onCreate(TitleMenu.java:55)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
03-21 00:12:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(31329):    ... 11 more
03-21 00:12:16.740: D/libEGL(31368): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
03-21 00:12:16.740: D/libEGL(31368): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
03-21 00:12:16.745: D/libEGL(31368): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
03-21 00:12:16.750: E/(31368): Device driver API match
03-21 00:12:16.750: E/(31368): Device driver API version: 23
03-21 00:12:16.750: E/(31368): User space API version: 23 
03-21 00:12:16.750: E/(31368): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
03-21 00:12:16.785: D/OpenGLRenderer(31368): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: why are you using 4 different `SharedPreference`s to store 4 values? you can store `SummonerIdA`, `SummonerNameA`, `SummonerLevelA` and `profileIconIdA` in the same `SharedPreference`.

Comment: I got into the habit of doing it like this, I just realized now by using so many key value pairs that its really unconventional it is. Im going to change it now :p. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to initialize `data`,`data1`,`data2` and `data3` instances of `SharedPreferences` before calling `edit()` method :

```
data = getSharedPreferences("pref_key", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
.....
data1 = getSharedPreferences("pref_key_data1", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data1.edit();
.....
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to stop the app from crashing or stopping. However now I'm getting a problem when I click log in, the app exits and I cant access it now. Haha I'm sure its just a logic error.